# How To Find $EXIST_HOME in eXist-db

Tags: macos, configuration-files, exist-db

I am trying to edit my config file, which I am told is located at `$EXIST_HOME/conf.xml`. However, when I type `$EXIST_HOME` into my terminal nothing happens, and I have no idea where to look for the file in my file system. I am using OSX, and installed eXist using the standalone GUI, and was not asked where to install files at setup.

How can I get to the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$EXIST_HOME` is just used to represent wherever you installed eXist to. On many Linux/Unix based systems (including Mac OS X) it is recommended to set this environment variable in your profile to the location where you installed eXist. If you do not, when you try to start eXist it will try and self-determine this from the location of its binaries.

If you installed eXist from the `.dmg` file which is provided for Mac OS X users, then you can drag and drop eXist to wherever you wish, however typically this would be `/Applications/eXist-db`.

If you installed eXist from the `.jar` installer by running `java -jar eXist-db-setup-2.2.jar` or double-clicking the Jar file (if your computer is configured to execute Jar files), then the second screen of the installer prompts you for the location to install eXist to. The default location set for Mac OS X is `/Applications/eXist-db`.

So if you didn't change the defaults, your $EXIST_HOME would be `/Applications/eXist-db`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue was that I was just running the `.dmg`, and so the `/Applications/eXist-db` folder didn't exist. When I installed using the `.jar` file, the folder was created.

Comment: When using the Mac OS X build, as well as running/mounting the `.dmg` you need to drag-and-drop `eXist-db` from the DMG's Finder Window into the `Applications` folder.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, as [adamretter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345314/how-to-find-exist-home-in-exist-db#comment58764837_35536823) correctly states, the default installation directory when using the Exist-DB installation disk image (.dmg) is `/Applications/eXist-db`. However, when you navigate to the `/Applications/eXist-db` folder and click on the exist-db icon, as if to open the directory for further browsing, all that happens is that the Exist-DB server starts. Less experienced Mac users might not realise that you have to right-click with the mouse on the Exist-DB icon in the Applications folder and choose 'Show Package Contents' from the menu in order to view the directories that sit beneath it.

The config.xml file can be found at:

`/Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/etc/config.xml`

P.S. Don't forget to make a backup copy before you start editing :)